# Recovery of the hash avatar on XMPP for facebook

Tags: facebook, xmpp, chat, asmack, avatar

I am using asmack as XMPP client for Facebook chat. I have a small problem with the recovery of 'hash of the avatar.
Vcard and Presence release a different hash for the same photo.

presence releases this fragment xml:

```
<presence to="-1397017951@chat.facebook.com/Simple Chat for facebook_9f178c85_4DFBAD2D51CCA" 
    from="-100001386664684@chat.facebook.com">
        <x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update">
            <photo>4315d3952f68dcc09fe5e2c656e7d73707d950ec</photo>
        </x>
</presence>
```

While using the vCard object is issued a different hash:
**4e935a5e328ddd204f08d4d7159712accaada491**

The avatar is the same
How come? I have to do some other operation to obtain the same hash?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the XMPP trace of what you send to the server after receiving that presence update?

If your client doesn't recognise the hash, it should be querying the server for it. Is this happening?

Is it possible that you're calculating the hash against the base64 encoded data rather than the raw data itself?